# Custom markers in Mapbox GL using React

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

Mapbox GL offers a method to add custom markers, however it takes `HTMLElement` as argument, which forces to use ReactDom to render a marker first, and then append it:

```
const placeholder = document.createElement('div');

const marker = ReactDOM.render(
  <div className='mapboxgl-marker'>
    <marker/>
  </div>, placeholder);

const markerRef = new mapboxgl.Marker(marker).setLngLat(position).addTo(map);
```

I feel that this is suboptimal solution, since it happens outside of the `render()` function.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: I wonder if you came to a solution using `render()`? This doesn't help with that, but slightly simpler code might make use of `renderToString()` or `renderToStaticMarkup()` from ReactDOMServer. For example use, see https://github.com/BikeRoutes/Explorer/blob/6d2eb0919763bc3b5f49ce6376b764b947501b3b/src/components/Map/Map.tsx#L235

Answer (score -5):

Extend a React component so that you can control how many times it renders by leveraging the `shouldComponentUpdate` function.

If you return `true` from this function, your `marker` will re-render.  It seems you only want to render once so you could hardcode your `shouldComponentUpdate` to always return false.  But then if you only want it to run once then what exactly is the concern?  Perhaps you want to conditionally re-render only under certain conditions so you can handle those in the `shouldComponentUpdate` function.

More info: `https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate